# Is there a difference between running DBUnit as a USER or OWNER of a schema

Tags: java, oracle, spring, dbunit

Currently I'm using DBUnit for testing my webservices.

When I specify the db user credentials with the OWNER of the schema everything works just fine.

If I change the db credentials to login as a USER I get:

```
> [Main Thread] ERROR org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - Table   
> 'ens_mrm_configuration' not found in   
> tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[],   
> _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
```

I'm aware the the OWNER should first grant SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT for all tables I want to access (so I did just that) I also created SYNONYMS to refer to the actual tables. In the end both scenario's work, but the first test fails with this ERROR If I run the tests as a USER.

So is there a difference how DBUnit handles this? Im currently working with dbunit 2.4.8 and SpringJUnit.

**UPDATE**
 So I found out that I made a mistake my bad. The tests actually don't
    work at all when I test with the USER credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly how are you creating the synonyms?

In Oracle, a synonym can be either public (in which case it is visible to all users) or private (in which case it is visible only to the owner of the synonym).  Are you creating public synonyms?  Or are you creating private synonyms?

Public synonyms are created using the `PUBLIC` keyword

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM ens_mrm_configuration
   FOR schema_owner.ens_mrm_configuration
```

while private synonyms are not

```
CREATE SYNONYM ens_mrm_configuration
   FOR schema_owner.ens_mrm_configuration
```

If you are creating private synonyms, the synonyms need to be created in the `USER` schema.

If you log in as `USER`, can you run this query and post the results

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_name = 'ENS_MRM_CONFIGURATION';
```